# Can't load dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I am very new to R programming and When I have tried to run "require(dplyr)", I get this error. I can't figure out why

```
Loading required package: dplyr
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘tibble.so’ not found
Warning message:
S3 methods ‘$.tbl_df’, ‘[.tbl_df’, ‘[[.tbl_df’, ‘row.names<-.tbl_df’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_df’, ‘as_data_frame.NULL’, ‘as_data_frame.data.frame’, ‘as_data_frame.default’, ‘as_data_frame.list’, ‘as_data_frame.matrix’, ‘as_data_frame.table’, ‘as_data_frame.tbl_df’, ‘as_tibble.NULL’, ‘as_tibble.data.frame’, ‘as_tibble.default’, ‘as_tibble.list’, ‘as_tibble.matrix’, ‘as_tibble.poly’, ‘as_tibble.table’, ‘as_tibble.tbl_df’, ‘as_tibble.ts’, ‘check_names_before_after.character’, ‘check_names_before_after.default’, ‘check_names_df.character’, ‘check_names_df.default’, ‘check_names_df.logical’, ‘check_names_df.numeric’, ‘format.tbl’, ‘format.tbl_df’, ‘format.trunc_mat’, ‘format_v.character’, ‘format_v.default’, ‘format_v.list’, ‘glimpse.data.frame’, ‘glimpse.default’, ‘glimpse.tbl’, ‘print.tbl’, ‘print.tbl_df’, ‘print.trunc_mat’, ‘quote_n.cha [... truncated]
```

Comment: Try to reinstall both `tibble` and `dplyr`.

Comment: Try install.packages('dplyr', dep = TRUE)

Comment: I've tried both recommendations, but I get the same result.

Comment: What version of R? What operating system?

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554786-Problem-Installing-Packages

Comment: I am using R Version 1.1.383 and the operating system is macOS Sierra

Comment: @ScipioneSarlo "4 out of 58 people found this helpful" in reference to your link

Answer (score 0):

It is not an elegant solution but have you tried

```
install.packages('tidyverse')
```